# How can I change image without changing url?

Tags: html, angularjs, cloudinary

I am uploading image directly in cloudinary and I got some url for that particular image. I pasted in angularjs(front end view) and everything is working.

```
<img class="full-image" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dl33ng89c/image/upload/v1456470892/mobile.jpg"/>
```

For example I got url like this:

```
 http://res.cloudinary.com/dl33ng89c/image/upload/v1456470892/mobile.jpg
```

How can I update my image without changing this url?

Any one help is appreciated.

Comment: Hmm. Why do you want to change image without changing url? What are you trying to do? Do you mean you replaced the image but it is cached by browser and does not update?

Comment: before i displayed one image now i want to update new image without changing that url

Comment: You can't change an image without another url..

Comment: no i checked some shopping sites same url daily they are changing images@Peurr

Comment: @komal We still have no idea what is the problem you are trying to solve. Why do you not want to change url? Do you think that would be easier? Can you gives an example site doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you cant do than.

Images will be cached by browser.so when you request the same url again,browser will get the image from cache and displays in browser.

in order to achieve what you want,i know two possible ways.

1. use cache bursting.i.e just send some dummy/random value in image url.

   src="/images/some_image.png?dummy=121212"

here dummy=121212 has nothing to do with your server.it just makes sure that image wont come from browser cache.

2. you can disable caching whole page from your server code. set http headers for your page.so browser will not cache you page when it loads in first place and it will fetch fesh copy from server always. 
   https header like `Cache-control: no-cache` , `Expires: 0`

Answer (score 0):

From what you're asking it sounds like you want to replace a statically served file. If that's so, you need some back-end processing to do what you want (some PHP, Java etc.). You'd need to overwrite the original image with the new image.
If you haven't got your own back-end already and your using another service (which it looks like you're doing), you're out if luck.

Answer (score 0):

When you update an image (upload while keeping the `public_id`, the image is overwritten on your Cloudinary account, but it's still cached in the CDN.

The recommended approach is to update the URL to use the new version value, as returned by the upload call. Alternatively, remove the version completely from your URL, and enable the `invalidate` flag for future uploads. See the following for more information:
https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520852-How-can-I-update-an-already-uploaded-image-